# Need to convert this into MongoDB form

Tags: sql, mongodb

```
SELECT Country_Region, MAX(Confirmed), MAX(Deaths) 
FROM `covid_19` 
GROUP BY Country_Region 
ORDER BY `MAX(Confirmed)` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Need to convert this into MongoDB form

Comment: Please post your data

Answer (score 2):

here is `mongodb` syntax equivalent:

```
db.covid_19.aggregate( [
  {
    $group: {
       _id: "$Country_Region",
       MaxConfirmed: { $max: "$Confirmed" },
       MaxDeath: {$max: "$Deaths"}
    }
  }, { $sort:{"MaxConfirmed":-1}}
   , { $limit: 10 }
] )
```